# Is every group a Galois group?

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, topological-groups

It is well-known that any finite group is the Galois group of a Galois extension. This follows from [Cayley's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem) (as can be seen in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/188621/19379)). This (linked) answer led me to the following question:

> What about infinite groups?

Infinite groups appear as Galois groups on infinite extensions, as when one defines the absolute Galois group of a field $F$. There is a natural topology on the Galois group, called the Krull topology, which turns this group into a [profinite group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_group) (i.e. a compact, totally disconnected, Hausdorff topological group). It can be proven that any profinite group is the Galois group of an extension (see this [short paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1974-042-02/S0002-9939-1974-0325587-3/S0002-9939-1974-0325587-3.pdf) by Waterhouse). Therefore, the above question is equivalent to the following:

> Can any group be given the structure of a profinite group?

I would like to get more information about this question. In particular, if the answer is no, are there definite restrictions (e.g. cardinality)?

Comment: I guess the answer is true considering every group is the fundamental group of a topological space.

Comment: @Honghao And every fundamental group is profinite?

Comment: @Honghao No, the Wikipedia page says that fundamental groups in topology are not pro-finite.

Comment: @Honghao: the analogy to covering spaces cannot be pushed too far. An algebraic field extension is determined by its finite subextensions in a way that a covering map is not.

Comment: Also see the Wikipedia link you gave about the pro-finite completion of a group.  You can see that a group can be made pro-finite if and only if its pro-finite completion is isomorphic via the natural map.  Then you can see that not even $\mathbb Z$ is pro-finite.

Comment: @Thomas: this appears to be false (that is, it's not true in general that the natural map from a profinite group to its profinite completion is an isomorphism). In other words, there exist profinite groups with non-closed subgroups of finite index.

Comment: Hmm, will have to rethink, @QiaochuYuan. I thought it followed from the universal property of the completion, but I could easily have been wrong.

Comment: @Thomas: consider $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\infty}$. There are obvious projection maps to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and then there are non-obvious ones: quotient by the direct sum and you obtain a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$, and any linear functional on this vector space gives you a map to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ whose kernel is not closed. So the profinite completion of $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\infty}$ as an abstract group is larger than the group itself.

Comment: An infinite group which is countably infinite cannot be given the structure of a profinite group. This is because a non-empty compact Hausdorff space without isolated points is uncountable. If $G$ is a profinite group with an isolated point, then every point is isolated, and the topology on $G$ is discrete, so $G$ is necessarily finite.

Comment: The "equivalence" is not quite so (I agree the topological version is perhaps the "correct" version). See Manfred Dugas, Rüdiger Göbel. *All infinite groups are Galois groups over any field*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc., **304 (1)**, (1987), 355-384.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No. Profinite groups are [residually finite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residually_finite_group) (in fact a group is residually finite if and only if it embeds into its [profinite completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_group#Profinite_completion)) and many groups are not residually finite. If you don't have any particular restriction on the number of generators, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a simple example.

There are other restrictions. A compact Hausdorff group has a [Haar measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) of total measure $1$ and no countable group can be equipped with such a measure since the measure of any singleton cannot be $0$ and cannot be positive. This rules out $\mathbb{Q}$ but it also rules out, for example, $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you. I am not familiar with residually finite groups. Do you know an example of a finitely generated group which is not residually finite?

Comment: @M Turgeon: yes, but they aren't trivial to construct; for example, some Baumslag-Solitar groups (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baumslag%E2%80%93Solitar_group) work, and there is a finitely presented example due to Higman: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman_group

Comment: In the second paragraph you probably mean Haar *probability* measure. Counting measure on a discrete group is a perfectly legitimate Haar measure. @MTurgeon one reason that explains why it is difficult to come up with examples of non-residually finite groups is that linear groups are residually finite.

Comment: @t.b.: yes, sorry. When you say "non-residually finite groups" you mean "non-residually finite finitely generated groups." $\mathbb{Q}$ is linear but it is not residually finite.

Comment: Yes, right. One nitpick deserves another one :) Nice answer!

Comment: @t.b. and Qiaochu Thank you for the extra comments!

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4939/is-there-a-compact-group-of-countably-infinite-cardinality/4950#4950

Answer (score 8):

This cannot be true since a profinite group cannot be countable ([see this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4939/is-there-a-compact-group-of-countably-infinite-cardinality)) so therefore we cannot make $\mathbb{Z}$ into a profinite group.