# Is there an algebraic extension $K / \Bbb Q$ such that $\text{Aut}_{\Bbb Q}(K) \cong \Bbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

> Is there an *algebraic* field extension $K / \Bbb Q$ such that $\text{Aut}_{\Bbb Q}(K) \cong \Bbb Z$?

Here I mean the field automorphisms (which are necessarily $\Bbb Q$-algebras automorphisms) of course.

According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871485), one can find some extension of $\Bbb Q$ whose automorphism group is $\Bbb Z$. But I've not seen that one can expect this extension to be algebraic.

At least such an extension can't be normal, otherwise $\Bbb Z$ would be endowed with a topology turning it into a profinite group, which [can't](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4939/is-there-a-compact-group-of-countably-infinite-cardinality) be countably infinite.
(So typically, if we replace $\Bbb Q$ by $\Bbb F_p$, then the answer to the above question is *no*, because any algebraic extension of a finite field is Galois).

Thank you!

Comment: Another reason for which an infinite countable group can't be profinite was given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188887)

Comment: Interestingly enough, [Fried and Kollár](https://eudml.org/doc/172744) showed that any finite group is the automorphism group of some finite extension of $\Bbb Q$ (which might not be Galois in general, so it doesn't solve the inverse Galois problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L$ be the fixed field of $\text{Aut}_{\Bbb Q}(K)$, so $\Bbb Q \subsetneq L \subset K$, and $K/L$ is a normal extension with Galois group $\Bbb Z$, which is impossible.

Comment: I see (details are written [here](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~len/d70/chap8.pdf)). The main point is that $\mathrm{Aut}(K / K^G)$ has a natural structure of profinite group, since we deal with algebraic extensions.

Comment: @Watson Maybe this is a dumb question. Why $Q$ is a proper field of $L$ here? What is being contradicted here?

Comment: @user45765 because $K/L$ is a Galois extension.

Comment: @KennyLau Sorry for dumbness. I could not see the full argument. Assume the proof goes by contradiction. Assume $K/Q$ is algebraic.(i.e. separable.) $K/L$ is galois and by galois group 1-1 correspondence, $L=Q$. Why $L\neq Q$ to start with here? Or I am heading towards the wrong thought? Thanks.

Comment: Anyway we don't really need a strict inclusion $\Bbb Q \subsetneq L$ (in my reasoning, I did not use it…) ? We just use that in our case, the automorphism group of $K / K^G$ is $G$ (since $G$ is the full automorphism group of $K$, i.e. $G= \Bbb Z$ by assumption) — see part (d) in the theorem of the document I cited.

Comment: @Watson I see. Thanks.

Comment: @Watson How does one deduce that $Q$ is proper subfield of $L$ here then?

Comment: @user45765 : this could be clarified by the author of the above answer…

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441260/is-it-true-that-operatornamegalk-kg-g-even-when-g-is-infinite

Comment: @Watson that is not related.

Comment: The following comment remains unanswered: "How does one deduce that $\Bbb Q$ is proper subfield of $L$ ?" ; moreover why would it be necessary to have a proper inclusion?

Comment: It isn't necessary; I don't know why you guys keep focussing on the wrong details.